# snapshot candy machine mint accounts in correct order of mint

Tags: solana, solana-web3js, metaboss

I would like to get all minted NFTs mint accounts in correct order(0 to last).
Like:

NFT#1 mint address: "2aiHs4d7nN8EZJAaMMeQ6LE856NJUEwZP2VRdtf8vXAJ",
NFT#2 mint address: "4E637AnAEQXYaPVSyBzgqGVuWF1oiruskNT2pfvmULHT",
..

I am using metaboss, but it doesn't give back the mint addresses in the correct order from 0 to last. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the order doesn't matter I believe, but if still you want them in order, you can use one of the following:-

- [Magic Eden Hashlist](https://magiceden.io/mintlist-tool) tool
- [Pentacle](https://pentacle.tools/nft-mints) tool